# Include records if related entities have a value using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to list only the DME's that have values in the Carga's related entities:

Main entity:

```
public partial class DME
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Carga> Cargas { get; set; } 
 }
```

Related Entity Carga:

```
public class Carga
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PesoLiquido { get; set; }
    public string PesoBruto { get; set; }
    public string Volume { get; set; }
}
```

PesoLiquido and PesoBruto can be NULL or "0" or "10.200"
   Valor can be NULL or "0" or "10.20"

Until now I was able to get this but with errors:

```
IList<DME> DMEs = db.DMEs
                    .Where(d => d.Cargas.Select(c => c.PesoLiquido) != null && d.Cargas.Sum(c => c.PesoLiquido) > 0)
                    .Where(d => d.Cargas.Select(c => c.PesoBruto) != null && d.Cargas.Sum(c => c.PesoBruto) > 0)
                    .Where(d => d.Cargas.Select(c => c.Valor) != null && d.Cargas.Sum(c => c.Valor) > 0))
```

Error:

```
Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this part of each Where:

```
d.Cargas.Select(c => c.PesoLiquido) != null
```

You are trying to compare a collection with null, which can't be translated to SQL.

Instead, do

```
d.Cargas.Any(c => c.PesoLiquido != null)
```

Also, by your posted code each of these properties is a string, and yet you are doing a sum, which likely won't translate either. Are these columns actually strings in the database or are they numeric?

If they are numbers in the database, change type of each property to `double?` and do:

```
   .Where(d => d.Cargas.Any(c => c.PesoLiquido > 0))
```

If they are strings for some reason, then do:

```
   .Where(d => d.Cargas.Any(c => c.PesoLiquido != null && c.PesoLiquido != "0.00")
```

Comment: Hi thanks, and this make the validation if value is greater then "0.00" to be a valid value  ?

Comment: @Patrick: sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I've updated my answer to provide more clarity.

Comment: Because I need to work with decimal values like 10.120 and 0.921 the only way I found to deal with it regarding validation, sums, dataanotation properties in ViewModels etc I finish storing them as string :S